# Unable to attach file name

Tags: php

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("image", $con);

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image ORDER BY file_name DESC LIMIT 1");

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $src = '"'.$row['file_name'].'"';
    $targ_w = $targ_h = 300;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;

    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

    header('Content-type: image/jpg');
    imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);

    exit;
}
?>
```

I am able to retrieve the file_name from the database by echoing, but i am unable to attach the file at this part `$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);` this is where it causes errors?
any idea?

Comment: Is there an error message that is generated when you run this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um... Because you're adding quotes to the filename for no reason?

Change `$src = '"'.$row['file_name'].'"';` to `$src = $row['filename'];`.

Comment: If this answer was satisfactory, please mark it as Accepted - see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) on "how to ask".

Comment: I wanted to get the last entry from the database, so i included this code.    
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image ORDER BY file_name DESC LIMIT 1");

but it doesn't update and get the latest entry.

Comment: That will get you the file with the highest position in the alphabet - so for instance something beginning with Z. If you have a file named Z.jpg, then add F.jpg, you will still get Z.jpg shown because it's further in the alphabet.

Comment: But i found from a website it says, 
To get the last entry add this to the end of the SQL query
Code:
ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1

So it doesn't work this way?

Comment: Usually you would have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field, typically called `id`. With that in place you can `ORDER BY id DESC` to get the most recent. Alternatively, a `TIMESTAMP` field with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` would work too.